# configuring turbogears2 with importerrors

Tags: python, importerror, turbogears

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MinimalApplicationConfigurator' from 'tg' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/__init__.py)
```

Help, i have installed tg it cant import 'MinimalApplicationConfigurator'. How can i resolve it? Tried putting the path directory on my mac terminal but with no succes. Can someone help?

Comment: Its working!! I dindt have my venv activated